# How do I unset an IP address set with ifconfig?

Tags: macos, mac, network

I recently used `ifconfig en1 1.2.3.4` to set the IP address of a network interface (specifically, the wireless card) on a Mac… How can I remove/unset it?

Using the graphical network configuration tool doesn't seem to change (or even be aware of) this address - when I use it to manually set an address, a second address is added to the device.

For example, right now `ifconfig` shows:

```
en1: flags=8863<UP,BROADCAST,SMART,RUNNING,SIMPLEX,MULTICAST> mtu 1500
    ether 00:23:xx:xx:xx:xx 
    inet 192.168.141.99 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.141.255
    inet 192.168.1.112 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.1.255
    media: autoselect
    status: active
```

The first address -  `141.99` - is the address I manually set. The second address — `1.112` — is the address assigned by my network's DHCP server.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use `delete`:

```
ifconfig en1 delete 192.168.141.99
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, I had to do `ifconfig en1 del 192.168.141.99` on Ubuntu.
Hope it helps someone.

Comment: @Frodik What's the difference?

Comment: `del` instead of `delete`

Comment: This  didn't work for me with IPv6.
The man page uses
`ifconfig en0 inet 192.0.2.45 -alias`
For IPv6, you can use `inet6` instead of `inet`. I tested and it works.

Answer (score 11):

To clear all ip address associated with en1:

```
sudo ifconfig en1 0.0.0.0
```

Comment: I confirm that this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I believe a reboot should reset it.

Comment: That might. But I'd rather leave it than sit through a reboot :P

Comment: A clear alternative, however this answer does not use of the ifconfig command as the question specified.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sudo ifconfig en1 down
sudo ifconfig en1 up
```

Comment: Sorry, but this doesn't work — the address persists past the down/up.

Comment: Did you ifconfig en1 back to your original address? If you didn't then it's obviously going to be the same one you had changed it to.

Comment: Sorry, my original question wasn't as clear as it could be. There was no “original address” - normally I have addresses assigned via DHCP, which now adds a second address to the interface.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you are looking to change the device en1 from 'static' to 'dhcp'. To do this perform the following:

```
sudo ipconfig set en1 BOOTP
sudo ipconfig set en1 DHCP
```

After making the config changes you will need to bring that interface down and back up:

```
sudo ifconfig en1 down
sudo ifconfig en1 up
```

Comment: Which version of ifconfig uses that syntax? The manpage for ifconfig on my machine (10.6.7) mentions nothing of either a `set` action or `dhcp`.

Comment: This may work on linux but it does not appear to work in BSD ifconfig that ships with MacOS.

Answer (score -2):

Try :

```
ifconfig en* down detach delete
```

Comment: Please could you expand this answer to explain what the various flags and options are doing?

Comment: and why does this work and other answers do not?